# How to use redirects in Docker

Tags: linux, docker

## Save Docker output to host

```
docker run centos cat /etc/hosts > asdf
```

"asdf" is saved in my host Linux.

## Save Docker output to container

```
docker run centos sh -c 'cat /etc/hosts > /tmp/asdf '
docker run centos cat /tmp/asdf
cat: /tmp/asdf: No such file or directory
```

It does not work, how can I cat the new file?

## Use "<" in container

```
docker run centos sh -c 'cat < /etc/hosts'
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

OK

## Read file with "<"

```
docker run centos cat < /etc/hosts
```

Nothing happens.

How can I cat a host file in a container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to understand the way your shell is parsing each of these commands, which dictates what Docker runs vs. what is done completely outside of Docker. I'll look at each case in turn.

### Save Docker output to the host

```
docker run centos cat /etc/hosts > asdf
```

First your shell will parse this line and find the `>` redirect, followed by a filename. It will open (or overwrite) a file named `asdf` first. Then it will run this command:

```
docker run centos cat /etc/hosts
```

And direct the standard output of that command into the already-open file `asdf`. Docker never knows anything about `asdf`, it is simply writing to standard output. The shell handles the file creation.

### Save Docker output to container

```
docker run centos sh -c 'cat /etc/hosts > /tmp/asdf '
```

Here, you have the redirect inside a quoted string, which is passed as an argument to the docker command. So far so good. Docker will create a new container (I'll refer to it as "A"), base it on the `centos` image, and execute this *inside the container* "A":

```
sh -c 'cat /etc/hosts > /tmp/asdf '
```

Since that happens inside container "A", the file which is created, is created inside the container, not on the outside host system.

Next, this is run:

```
docker run centos cat /tmp/asdf
```

There are no redirects here, so the `cat` command is passed to Docker as-is. Here you are using `docker run` again. Docker will create another new container here, which I'll call "B". It is **not** running this command in container "A", that is a completely different container (though they are both based on the `centos` image).

The file was created in container "A", but now you are trying to read it in container "B". Since containers are completely separate, and each have their own filesystem, the file does not exist in container "B". Thus, you get the error.

```
cat: /tmp/asdf: No such file or directory
```

### Use "<" in container

```
docker run centos sh -c 'cat < /etc/hosts'
```

Once again, the `<` redirection is inside quotes and is passed as an argument. This is all happening inside the container. A new container "C" is created, based on `centos`, and the `cat` command reads and prints the file.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

### Read file with "<"

```
docker run centos cat < /etc/hosts
```

Here the `<` redirect is not quoted, so your shell interprets this before it is passed to Docker. What is really run is this:

```
docker run centos cat
```

Docker will create a new container "D", based on the `centos` image, and inside that container it will run the `cat` command. Since `cat` has nothing to do, it just exits, and so does your container.

Meanwhile, the redirection has hooked standard input to stream the contents of your host's `/etc/hosts` file. But, you did not use interactive mode (`-i`), so the container is not listening to standard input; it is ignored.

If you do you use `-i`, then your main host's `/etc/hosts` file would be printed.

### How to do what you were trying to do

Originally you were trying to redirect a file to another file inside the container, and then cat it. Unfortunately what you did was make a copy of the file in one container, but then try to read it in a different container (where it did not exist). There are a couple of ways you could accomplish this.

You could just run both commands in the same `docker run`:

```
docker run centos sh -c 'cat /etc/hosts > /tmp/asdf; cat /tmp/asdf'
```

If you have an already running container, you could use `docker exec`:

```
docker exec <container-id> 'cat /etc/hosts > /tmp/asdf'
docker exec <container-id> 'cat /tmp/asdf'
```

Comment: Great answer, after read this, I totally understood!Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> how can I cat a host file in container?

If that container immediately exits, you need to commit that stopped container into a new image, and then:

```
docker run new_image cat /tmp/asdf
```